# How to use IF function with 3 arguments while ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Okay so my question is how do i use IF with 3 arguments while one of the arguments is "Ignore blanks".

If A1 is "Escalation_complaint or "Escalation_request" B1 must show "Escalated".
If A1 is any other text, B1 must show "Solved"
If A1 is blank, B1 must remain empty.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: You need two ifs(), one inside the other. I’ll let you learn by implementation.

Comment: There are some answers that, that depending on your input data, all may be correct. So best is to include markdown sample data and include your own attempt. See [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the text will always be Escalation_complaint or Escalation_request, you can do this with a nested IF query. =IF in Excel takes three parameters: what to verify, result if true, and result if false. You can have another IF statement in the what to do if it returns false section. We can also do an OR() statement to verify both Escalation_complaint and Escalation_request. The result looks like this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="Escalation_complaint",A1="Escalation_request"),"Escalated",IF(A1="","","Solved"))
```

The order here is important because you want the "for all other cases" to be in the final IF statement.

If you have a situation where you could also have "Request_escalation" or "complaint_escalation", you should make a more general solution that uses SEARCH or FIND which would allow you to do a more general lookup that allows for more values without having to hardcode them. Here is an example that makes it possible to find the word Escalation anywhere in the cell:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("escalation",A1,1),0)>0, "Escalated", IF(A1="","","Solved"))
```

Comment: No worries :) This query makes sure you only compare the values you want to find. If you do the LEFT(A1,3)="Esc" you will incorrectly match cells if they begin with "escaped" for example. If you want to be able to find all cells that contain the word "escalation" you could do the SEARCH("escalation",A1,1) which will find both escalation_request as well as requested_escalation. Error handling can be done with IFERROR(SEARCH("escalation",A1,1),0) meaning 1 if it finds it, and 0 if it doesn't (which in this case becomes an error). You should mark answers as solved if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 1):

So, using two if(), and minimising the testing you need :

```
=IF(left(A1,3)="Esc","Escalated",IF(A1="","","Solved"))
```

Edit: Based on a comment to another answer, if testing for "esc" only could lead to problems then how about:

```
=IF(left(A1,5)="Escal","Escalated",IF(A1="","","Solved"))
```

Which will avoid words like "escaped" or "escargot"...

Comment: This works beautifully in excel. Does is also work in Google Sheets?

Comment: The comment I made was leaning in to making a general solution that would allow fleshing this out, rather than your specific solution that only works for this particular situation. You also have the possibility of "request_escalated" or "complaint_escalated" which this solution will not find. That is why I also suggested the =SEARCH() solution which allows for the word "escalated" anywhere and is also case insensitive.

Comment: @MagneTism and if the word is “escalate” not “escalated” then yours stops... but you are adding things the OP did not request - I kept it simple to match the question.

Comment: We are all here to learn. OP might not have covered all cases with the explanation, and someone else might stumble on to this question with a similar, but not identical need. I'd rather see that we try and teach the reasoning behind the answers than just specific answers that can only be applied for this specific situtaion.

Answer (score 1):

Your first test must be whether the A1 is empty or not. This must be the first because if you test whether an empty string is contained in another string the answer is always yes. `=SEARCH("","Something")` returns 1. So, How do you test for an empty cell? I recommend Excel's COUNTA() function but you may prefer testing for "". So, let's say, your first test is this.

`=IF(COUNTA(A1), True, False)`

Some would say `IF(COUNTA(A1)>0, True, False)` and that is equivalent. The simple `IF(COUNTA(A1)` tests for non-zero. Any number other than zero returns True.

So, now you got your basic function. What's supposed to happen if the result is True? What do you want to happen if the result is False? The latter is easy. If the result is False you want a null string returns. So, now your formula looks like this:-

`=IF(COUNTA(A1), True, "")`

Observe that we simply replaced the *False* with the desired output. So, what do you want to happen if A1 has something in it, if the first test resulted in *True*? There are two possibilities. That makes the problem solvable with a single IF. IF A1 has something starting with "Escalation" in it the result should be "escalate", else it should be "solved". So, how do you test for cell content?

`=Find("escalation", A1)` will not find "Escalation" (with a capital E). Therefore I recommend SEARCH(), which does.

`=SEARCH("escalation", A1)` should return 1. If it returns 1 your problem is solved because if it returns any other number its not "escalated" but "solved". Unfortunately, there is a third option. It might return an error. In fact it will return an error every time the word isn't found. That gives you a 3-way possibility (1, bigger than 1, or Error) which can't be solved with a single IF. So, I suggest to avoid the error.

`=Find("escalation", A1 & "escalation")` will find the word "escalation" every time. But it will find it in first position only if the conditions for "Escalate" is met. Therefore the formula for the True condition in the basic formula must be this:-

`IF(SEARCH("escalation", A1 & "escalation") = 1, "Escalated", "Solved")`

That's it. Assemble the second IF into the first and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Excel have maximum 30 arguments in a formula.

```
= if (A1=1, "True",if(B1>2,"True", "false"))
```

Understand this pattern. easy way.
If you no longer understand this, or if your problem has not been resolved, attach a file or screenshot that relates to your problem.

Comment: You don’t show 30 arguments, first if() is true or false, and so is the second. The test can evaluate as many items as you care to trst as long as that result is true or false...